# Type of drupal cache to be cleared on new hook implementation

Tags: caching, drush

If I implement a new hook which cache type(like menu, css+js, etc) should I clear for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Duplicate question (newer but with more answers): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/167373

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [`module_implements()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) function, it uses the following code to reset the hook cache:

```
cache_set('module_implements', array(), 'cache_bootstrap');
drupal_static_reset('module_hook_info');
drupal_static_reset('drupal_alter');
cache_clear_all('hook_info', 'cache_bootstrap');
```

You can just use the same code to do it yourself.